# How to get all content between two curly brackets, ignoring those in quotation marks?

Tags: regex

I'm currently using the following regex with partial success:

```
/\{[^{}]+\}/g
```

But it fails for this situation:

```
{get('{')} {b} {abc'}'d}
```

I just want to ignore the `{` and `}` when they are between quotation marks, and get the right result:

```
get('{')
```

and

```
b
```

and

```
abc'}'d
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex to capture inner strings for both cases:

```
\{((?:[^{}']*'[^']*')*[^{}']*)\}
```

Assuming quotes are balanced and unescaped.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zwFxqo/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\{`: Match a `{`
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

    - `[^{}']*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `{` and not `}` and not `'`
    - `'`: Match a single quote
    - `[^']*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `'`
    - `'`: Match a single quote
  - `)*`: End non-capture group. Match 0 or more of this group
  - `[^{}']*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `{` and not `}` and not `'`
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `\}`: Match a `}`

Comment: it does not work, for this text "{abc'}'d}", what the expected result is "{abc'}'d}"， but the actual result is "{abc}"

Comment: Check my updated answer and new demo link. It should work fine now as long as quote are balanced and unescaped.